# Customize the TFS Scrum board

Tags: scrum, tasks, tfs, board

Here is a TFS Scrum board I got from Internet:

[image]

I want to know if it is possible to customize the card, as it does have the name of attributed person as redundant information. I would want to replace it by the Severity / Business Value of the related Bug / Product Backlog Item.

The following image has the relevant fields I would like to change surrounded with a red rectangle:

[image]

Comment: Hi Sergio, I was going to answer how this is done in Azure DevOps (it is easy), but see you are using TFS. What version are you using?

Comment: @MichaelBosesPMP About Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version 12.0.40629.0  © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.